# Get notification (message) to web using JavaScript

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase to send notification (using token) to both android and IOS and applications are working fine. Now my requirement is:

- When apps receive a notification, that time notification is also received in web application.

How it is possible, suggest me.
Thanks.

I am using code by using link:
https://rakibul.net/fcm-web-js
but this is work for browser notification.

Answer (score 0):

Sending is the same.

If you have some account for each user, you can group them under the device groups and then send it to all of them at one time.

Frontend is same as in your link.

By https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group

1. create device group

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/notification
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=API_KEY
project_id:SENDER_ID

{
   "operation": "create",
   "notification_key_name": "appUser-Chris",
   "registration_ids": ["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

This returns you notification_key, which you can save to your users account.

2. If you want to add another device for the user, call

```
{
   "operation": "add",
   "notification_key_name": "appUser-Chris",
   "notification_key": "APA91bGHXQBB...9QgnYOEURwm0I3lmyqzk2TXQ",
   "registration_ids": ["51"]
}
```

And you can then send your message to the notification_key insted of registration_id.

Comment: Thanks Pavel for reply,
I think group is worked for devices (like android and IOS).

Android and IOS getting notification but I need to get these notification on Web using javascript.

Comment: @AkramKhan it's the same - you need to get registration_id from device (and it doesn't metter whether it is android, ios or web).
So you get registration_ids from all devices of the user, get notification_key for them and now you can send messages to this notification_key and receive it on all devices (including browser)

Comment: @AkramKhan I think you just need SSL certificate on your web